# How to get today,yesterday,or day name in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to send message to chat user and then I store my message with date in parse format to my database.
So when I have to get chat history I have to show time like this:

1. if date is today show time (3pm etc)
2. if date is one day previous show yesterday
3. if day is within the same week show day name (i.e. Sunday etc)
4. all others show exact date

I have tried this:

```
var now = moment(new Date()); //todays date
var end = moment("2015-12-1"); // another date
var differn = now.diff(end, 'days');
```

How can I do this in JavaScript? I have tried to use momentjs.

Comment: Take a look at the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is the following:

```js
function getMyText(date){
  if( !moment.isMoment(date) ){
    date = moment(date); // ok for js date, milliseconds or string in ISO format
  }
  
  if( date.isSame(moment(), 'day') ){
    return date.format('hh:mm a');
  } else if( date.isSame(moment().subtract(1, 'd'), 'day') ){
    return 'Yesterday';
  } else if( date.isSame(moment(), 'week') ){
    return date.format('dddd');
  } else {
    return date.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }
}

var input = [
  moment(), // now
  moment().subtract(22, 'h'), // 22 hours ago
  moment().subtract(3, 'd'),  // 3 days ago
  moment().subtract(6, 'd'),  // 6 days ago
  moment().subtract(15, 'd')  // 15 days ago
];

for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  console.log( getMyText(input[i]) );
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It uses moment [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: nice, beat me to it :)

Comment: @alebianco just for few seconds, your answer is nice too :)

Answer (score 2):

since you're already using moment.js, you can leverage the calendar time functionality

```js
var formats = {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}
var date = new Date()
var output = moment().calendar(date, formats);
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

take a look at the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) for more examples

Comment: @NazarHussain please mark an answer as accepted if it solves your issue, you get also +2 reputation for it.

Comment: you should see a tick under the voting buttons next to the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work